# clean up big Java set/list to easy memory usage

Tags: java, set

I have a big Integer Set, containing about 5.3M Integer, then I pass this Set to method-1 to process. after that i have lots of more steps to go, my question is with this big Integer set, it consumes lots of memory. is there any way i can release those memory after method-1 so the following method can execute without out of memory?

I tried the followings:

```
myBigIntegerSet.clear()
```

and

```
myBigIntegerSet = null
```

I don't know if this is gotta help the memory usage at all, and if they are, which one works better? Thanks!

Comment: With `null`, you'll have potentially one more object GC'ed.

Comment: That is what seems to be the requirement: To make the object to be GCed so to free space. But GC is not in developer control. So, you can never be sure if the GC will run before/after the (likely) "Out of Memory" error.

Comment: @bgth The JVM won't throw an `OutOfMemoryError` without first attempting to reclaim memory. If you see an `OutOfMemoryError` then you can be certain that the garbage collector ran before it was thrown, but wasn't able to free up enough space for execution to continue.

Comment: @JonK I agree. My mistake. GC will run at least once before throwing out of memory

Answer (score 0):

An object can only be garbage collected when there are no ways of to reach that object any more. So in the  following example:

```
Set<Integer> myBigIntegerSet= new HashSet<Integer>();
Map<String, Set<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
Mymap.put("test", myBigIntegerSet);
myBigIntegerSet= null;
```

myBigIntegerSet will still not be garbage collected because myBigIntegerSet refers to it. Similarly clear makes all the elements null. However it still cannot be garbage collected if it is being used by other objects.

```
myBigIntegerSet.clear();
```

Nullifying all the objects that refers to myBigIntegerSet should solve the problem. I would suggest to use object's finalize method to do so.